# Svn2git: Add revision number to git commit title

Tags: git, svn, commit, revision, svn2git

I want to add the svn revision to every git commit title, so can I can see every Revision in each commit in the history of our Team Foundation Server.

I already tried editing a commit with "--amend", but this way it just makes a new commit (and the history becomes incorrect). Also I dont wanna edit every commit one by one.
[Screenshot of what I wanna archieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW6z4.png)
The Screenshot shows what I did with --ammend.

I'm using svn2git for the Migration.

Answer (score 1):

There are pleny tools called `svn2git`. If you are not using the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it's very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will easily be able to configure it for your layout to get the result you want and expect.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of a SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

With the latest merged pull requests you can even fulfill your request with it. Just get and compile the sources or wait until a new release is done. Then you can use the `--add-metadata` switch in combination with the `--msg-filter` switch which is applied after `--add-metadata`, so in the `--msg-filter` process you can take the automatically added metadata with the revision number and move or copy it to the end of the first line of the commit message.

Answer (score 0):

You can have several options to do it:

1. Modify the commit message and store the content in your commit message.
2. Add metadata to the commit.

---

### ***`Modify the commit message`***

Like you mentioned in your question is you do a `git commit --amend` its actually a `rebase`. `rebase` modify the commit and change the SHA-1.

You wish to avoid it, so you will need to set the message before committing.
Here is why it's happening, since the message is part of the metadata which calculated when generating the SHA-1.

[image]

---

### ***`Add metadata to the commit.`***

If you want to add extra data to the commit **after** you have committed the nest way is simply to add `notes`. Notes is not part of the metadata used to generate the SHA-1 so you can add it after the commit was made.

```
git notes add -m 'Old commit is: xxxxxx'
```

Comment: Is there any way to search for the note in Team Foundation Server History? As far as I see I can only search for commit ID. The reason why we want the revision number in the title is because we want to simply search for it by using Strg+F search function in browser.

Comment: Im not using TFS, im a command line user :-)
in command line us the `git log --grep ...`