# How to find svn project author after migrate the project from svn to git?

Tags: git, svn

There are some `tar.gz` file in a project migrated from `svn` to `git`, and i should check `who and when` this `tar.gz` file `added`. For there are some of them were added `after` the project migrated from `svn` to `git`, and i can easy to check author and data by using `git log *.tar.gz`. But some added `before` the project migrated and when i use `git log .tar.gz`, the `author` and `date` was who pushed this project to git rather than real author. Are there any way i can check the real author of this files?

Comment: It depends on how project migrated ? .. you only can see author what you can see in `git log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the project was migrated in one operation (git init, add the content of the svn repo), without migrating each svn revision, then no, you cannot see who added those tar.gz, and when.

If the project was migrated with [svn2git](https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git) (promoted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37118661/6309) by [Vampire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589329/vampire)), then you should see the log with the same `git log` command.